# If the two ends of a rope in equilibrium are pulled with forces of equal magnitude and opposite directions, why isn’t the total tension in the rope 0?

Tags: forces

"If the two ends of a rope in equilibrium are pulled with forces of equal magnitude and opposite directions, why isn’t the total tension in the rope zero?"

Can someone explain why the TOTAL tension is zero? Because I do get that the tension force is present and is therefore not zero, but I don't get why the TOTAL tension is zero.

Comment: Related and/or dupe of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/134273/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/378600/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41291/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/214074/25301, etc

Comment: Force is a vector quantity having both magnitude and direction. Since the forces are equal and opposite, they add up to 0. On the other hand, the applicable force in terms of the load on the rope, the forces effectively add as if they were in the same direction, and double stress gives you double the strain.  Tensions can be strong enough to break the rope without accelerating it before hand.

Comment: The net force on the rope is what is zero. Not the tension in the rope.

Comment: The question seems to be more about semantics than about physics, and a  rephrased version of it might consequently be directed to the Linguistics SE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the direction of Tension Force in a rope pulled at its two ends with equal forces?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/378600/what-is-the-direction-of-tension-force-in-a-rope-pulled-at-its-two-ends-with-equ)

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the tension isn't a force. Force is a vector, tension (or more generally, *stress*) is a tensor. The Cauchy stress tensor measures the forces applied *across* an arbitrary flat surface element dividing the rope. In a static situation, the force one side applies to the other is balanced by the force the other side applies on the first, but these forces *cannot be added together* (and thus cancel out) because they are talking about forces being applied to *different bits of the rope*.

(It should be noted, when talking about the effect of forces on the *centre of mass* of a compound body, forces can be added because they're being applied to the same thing. Force is the rate of change of momentum of some defined body or collection of bodies. The momentum of the centre of mass is a single thing. The momentum of the two halves of a rope are separate things.)

The net force on any bit of the rope is zero, because all the forces are being applied to the same object, and thus can be added. The net stress (or tension) on any part of the rope is non-zero, because every bit of the rope applies non-zero forces to each of its neighbouring parts.